# How to install bitcoind (Bitcoin Core) on Ubuntu?

Tags: bitcoind, linux, installation

I want to install a command line-only full node `bitcoind` on a mini PC with 4GB RAM and Ubuntu. What are the steps to do it and how can I check if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `useradd bitcoin` and `passwd bitcoin`
2. link `/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin` to external HDD with `chown -R bitcoin:bitcoin`
3. `git clone bitcoin core` in `/home/USER/GitStuff`
4. add bitcoin ppa repository
5. `sudo apt install libdb4.8-dev && sudo apt install libdb4.8++-dev`
6. `/autogen.sh` in `/home/USER/GitStuff/bitcoin`
7. `/configure --without-gui` (to build without GUI pass --without-gui)
8. `make`
9. `make install`
10. `su bitcoin`
11. start `bitcoind` (as user `bitcoin`)
12. `curl -sL https://bitnodes.earn.com/api/v1/nodes/me-8333 | jq`

Answer (score 1):

**Dependencies**

To get add-apt-repository, which we will use later to add the bitcoin PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install bitcoind`

**Configuration**

Before starting bitcointd you'll want to create directory and the bitcoin.conf configuration file:

`cd ~/`

`mkdir .bitcoin`

`cd .bitcoin`

`vim bitcoin.conf` or `nano bitcoin.conf`

**In bitcoin.conf these content are important:**

```
server=1
testnet=1
rpcuser=UNIQUE_RPC_USERNAME
rpcpassword=UNIQUE_RPC_PASSWORD
```

If you wish to use this installation on the regular bitcoin network, remove `testnet=1`

Comment: I think is an unnecessary command `mkdir .bitcoin`

Comment: When adding ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin it says: NOT MAINTAINED. The OS-library linking packages here had a series of issues.

PLEASE DOWNLOAD DIRECTLY FROM bitcoincore.org (and verify the signatures of said files).

Answer (score 1):

The custom apt repository now states it is unmaintained, and to use the snap found here:
https://github.com/bitcoin-core/packaging/tree/main/snap

```
sudo snap install bitcoin-core
```

Config file wants to live at: `/home/yourusername/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide in the docs of the bitcoin source code that goes over how to build bitcoin as well as the dependencies needed. Within that same directory of the source (doc/) there are various other guides and explanations that you may find useful as well.

[Linux build doc](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#ubuntu--debian)

Comment: Thanks, I actually would have added this and others once I refine my answer. I just wanted to put it out there for a start yesterday.